# How to create an R function which uses ggplot to generate chosen company's stock chart?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, plot, automation

I have a data frame with three columns and many rows (a snippet is shown below). The `company_name` column has many more companies other than just Facebook.

df

| date | price | company_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-04-23 | 20 | facebook |
| 2015-04-24 | 23 | facebook |
| 2015-04-25 | 30 | facebook |

If I have to create a stock chart for facebook `(y-axis = price and x-axis = date)`, I can do it easily using `dplyr` and `ggplot2` as follows:

```
facebook_chart <- 
  df %>%
  filter(company_name == "facebook") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=date, y=price)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title="Price Chart: Facebook") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

The above code generates the graph.

I tried to write a function that can do the same for other companies in the df (see below), however, after many attempts, I have failed and could not get a direction. Would be appreciated if anyone can help in this regard.

### my attempt at making the function - FAILED

```
myplotfunction <- function(df, company) {
    df %>%
    filter(company_name == "company")  %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=date, y=PRC)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(title="Price Chart: {{company}}") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
}

myplotfunction(df, facebook)
```

Comment: Try with `filter(company_name == company)` and `myplotfunction(df, "facebook")`.

Comment: stefans comment should fix it, but there is another thing with the title: use `labs(title=paste0("Price Chart: ",company))`

Comment: Thank you, Stefan and Jonas, both of your comments helped my query. Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to the forum! Have you tried function ```chartSeries``` from ```quantmod``` library?